# let 3 images stick to the center of the bottom of the parent div, next to each other

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

That above is basically my problem. I already browsed some other questions on SO, but the one closest was about *1* element, that doesn't have to be in the center.

I basically have three images next to each other in an invisible wrapper div, found here:  http://korilu.nl/maurits/search.html

What I want is to prevent the two images that are small from going up and down when one is clicked.
I tried to put `position:relative;` on the wrapper and `position:absolute; bottom:0;` on the images as suggested in question mentioned above, but then they are not in the middle anymore, but over eachother in the upperleft corner. How do I do this?

**EDIT:** Or top or center, I dont care, as long as they stop moving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to alter your jQuery script:

```
$("a").click(function(){
                $(current).animate({
                    opacity: .5,
                    height: '100px', 'margin-top': '100px'
                });
                $("img", this).animate({height: '200px','margin-top': '0px', opacity: 1});
                current = "#" + $(this).find("img").attr("id");
            });
```

Note the two new occurences of margin-top. Tried it on your site and works as you want it.

Comment: Thanks! I would never have thought of a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
#icons
{
  text-align:center;
  height:20%;
  display: block;
  width: 405px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#icons a
{
  float: left;
}
```

Get rid of the margin/padding you have on one of the links right now.
I set the width to 405px cause you might have some styling that pushes one of them to the next line otherwise.

Comment: I can't accept 2 answers, so I accepted Paul's answer because I understanded his better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try making the wrapper div relative as well, then absolute property will count from the wrapper instead of the whole document.

You can then position by setting left:0; bottom:0; and right:0; bottom:0;  for the left and right icons.